# Is spring MongoRepository thread safe

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, nosql

I know MongoRepository uses MongoTemplate internally to execute operations. MongoTemplate is thread safe. is MongoRepository thread safe?

Comment: No database can read your mind when it comes to isolation.  That's true of SQL and NoSQL instances.  MongoDB is not ACID.

Comment: @duffmo — The question was not about isolation but thread-safety.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. Unless otherwise noted, all Spring components provided by the framework are thread-safe once you get them injected into a client component.